# convert external cell address into range in vba

Tags: string, excel, vba, range, external

I have a string in cell A1, which is the cell address of an external cell (i.e. another workbook),

```
'[data transfer utility.xlsb]Sheet1'!$B$5
```

In vba I would like to create a range object, `myRange`, that would correspond to the address stored in cell A1.

I've tried various solutions, but none have worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VBA:

```
Function Reference(strAddress As String) As Range

    Dim intPos As Integer, intPos2 As Integer
    Dim strWB As String, strWS As String, strCell As String

    intPos = InStr(strAddress, "]")
    strWB = Mid(strAddress, 2, intPos - 2)

    intPos2 = InStr(strAddress, "!")
    strWS = Mid(strAddress, intPos + 1, intPos2 - intPos - 2)

    strCell = Mid(strAddress, intPos2 + 1)

    Reference = Workbooks(strWB).Worksheets(strWS).Range(strCell)

End Function
```

Comment: This works Peter, Had to modify the code slightly :
    
Function Reference(strAddress As String) As Range

    Dim intPos As Integer, intPos2 As Integer
    Dim strWB As String, strWS As String, strCell As String

    intPos = InStr(strAddress, "]")
    strWB = Mid(strAddress, 2, intPos - 2)

    intPos2 = InStr(strAddress, "!")
    strWS = Mid(strAddress, intPos + 1, intPos2 - intPos - 1)

    strCell = Mid(strAddress, intPos2 + 1)

   Set Reference = Workbooks(strWB).Worksheets(strWS).Range(strCell)

End Function

Comment: sorry, I can't get the code tags to work, could someone edit this for me please?  If you could post some help beyond the (useless) markdown editing help it would be great.
Am I doing something wrong, I've tried entering 4 spaces before the line where the code starts?  Now it won't even let me edit my own comment.

Comment: Edited the code above including your corrections. if you want to paste code in the comments, use `\`Inline code\`` or `<pre>Code</pre>`.

Answer (score 0):

In VBA:

```
ExecuteExcel4Macro("'C:\[Book1.xlsx]Sheet1'!" & Range("A1").Address(, , xlR1C1))
```

In Excel:

```
='C:\[Book1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$1
```

Comment: Thanks Philip, didn't understand this at first, but have just researched it some more and it seems to work!

Comment: using ExecuteExcel4Macro can be a bit daunting but allows you to reference data in a closed workbook, no need to open before hand.

Answer (score 0):

Whoever enters this dark place looking for hope, use this:

```
Function GetRangeReference(strAddress As String)
  Dim exclamationPos As Integer
  Dim strWBWS, strWB, strWS, strCell As String

  exclamationPos = InStrRev(strAddress, "!")

  If (exclamationPos > 0) Then
    strWBWS = Mid(strAddress, 1, exclamationPos - 1)

    If (Mid(strWBWS, 1, 1) = "'" And Mid(strWBWS, Len(strWBWS), 1) = "'") Then
      strWBWS = Mid(strWBWS, 2, Len(strWBWS) - 2)

      If (Mid(strWBWS, 1, 1) = "[" And InStr(strWBWS, "]") > -1) Then
        strWB = Mid(strWBWS, 2, InStrRev(strWBWS, "]") - 2)
        strWS = Mid(strWBWS, InStrRev(strWBWS, "]") + 1)
      Else
        strWB = ActiveWorkbook.Name
        strWS = Mid(strWBWS, InStrRev(strWBWS, "]") + 1)
      End If
    Else
      strWB = ActiveWorkbook.Name
      strWS = strWBWS
    End If

    strCell = Mid(strAddress, exclamationPos + 1)
  Else
    strWB = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    strWS = ActiveSheet.Name
    strCell = strAddress
  End If

  Set GetRangeReference = Workbooks(strWB).Worksheets(strWS).Range(strCell)
End Function`
```

Answer (score 0):

This handles R1C1 addresses and table names too:

```
Function GetRangeReference(strAddress As String) As Range
  Dim exclamationPos As Integer
  Dim strWBWS As String, strWB As String, strWS As String, strCell As String

  exclamationPos = InStrRev(strAddress, "!")

  If (exclamationPos > 0) Then
    strWBWS = Mid(strAddress, 1, exclamationPos - 1)

    If (Mid(strWBWS, 1, 1) = "'" And Mid(strWBWS, Len(strWBWS), 1) = "'") Then
      strWBWS = Mid(strWBWS, 2, Len(strWBWS) - 2)

      If (Mid(strWBWS, 1, 1) = "[" And InStr(strWBWS, "]") > -1) Then
        strWB = Mid(strWBWS, 2, InStrRev(strWBWS, "]") - 2)
        strWS = Mid(strWBWS, InStrRev(strWBWS, "]") + 1)
      Else
        strWB = ActiveWorkbook.Name
        strWS = Mid(strWBWS, InStrRev(strWBWS, "]") + 1)
      End If
    Else
      strWB = ActiveWorkbook.Name
      strWS = strWBWS
    End If

    strCell = Mid(strAddress, exclamationPos + 1)
  Else
    strWB = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    strWS = ActiveSheet.Name
    strCell = strAddress
  End If
  
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Set ws = Workbooks(strWB).Sheets(strWS)
  
  Dim rx As Object
  Set rx = CreateObject("VbScript.Regexp")
  rx.pattern = "R(\d+)C(\d+):R(\d+)C(\d+)"
  If rx.Test(strCell) Then
    Dim data: Set data = rx.Execute(strCell)
    Dim rTL As Range: Set rTL = ws.Cells(CLng(data(0).submatches(0)), CLng(data(0).submatches(1)))
    Dim rBR As Range: Set rBR = ws.Cells(CLng(data(0).submatches(2)), CLng(data(0).submatches(3)))
    
    Set GetRangeReference = ws.Range(rTL, rBR)
  Else
    On Error GoTo tryRange
    Set GetRangeReference = ws.Range(strCell)
  End If
  Exit Function
tryRange:
  Set GetRangeReference = Range(strAddress)
End Function
```